# PJSIP how to register pjsip_endpoint

Tags: pjsip

I currently have a good working version of siprtp.c (http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/page_pjmedia_samples_siprtp_c.htm) from PJSIP.

Now I wan't to use this to test my deployed sip server, but this deployed server requires the client to be registered to dial the echo extension. I really don't know where to start to achieve this.

Kind regards,
Daan

Comment: You want to register pjsip client account to the sip server using sip:username@sipserverIP:sipserverPort. what did you using,  ios/android for client?

Comment: No I have the siprtp_c example program. With this I want to test a professional SIP server but I need to use authentication to call this 'proxy authentication required'. I thus need to extend the siprtp_c program to do this authentication before starting the call.